# How to programmatically select nodes in Package Explorer in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, package-explorer

Does anybody know or have an example on how to select node(s) programmatically in the Package Explorer view in Eclipse plugin? I see some help on how to get current selection but not on how to set them.

Thanks.

Comment: hi can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do on package explorer. or what you are trying to override there

Comment: Already answered here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335491/how-to-programmatically-change-the-selection-within-package-explorer)

Answer (score 5):

Although a commenter has already pointed to a solution, it uses internal API.  If you wanted a a portable API implementation try this.  It will select all "open" projects in your workspace.

```
List<Object> openProjects = new ArrayList<Object>();

for( IProject project : ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects() )
{
    if( project.isOpen() )
    {
        final IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create( project );

        if( javaProject != null )
        {
            openProjects.add( javaProject );
        }

        openProjects.add( project );
    }
}

Object[] projectsToSelect = openProjects.toArray();
IViewPart view = window.getActivePage().showView( "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer" );
view.getSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection( new StructuredSelection( projectsToSelect ) );
```