# How to programmatically change the selection within package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, package-explorer

I am currently developing a plugin for eclipse that analyzes dependencies and references between projects within the Eclipse Workspace and displays them in its own View in a UML-like diagram.

To increase the usefulness of my plugin, I wish to add interactivity to the diagram by allowing users to open a project in the package explorer and if applicable open it in an editor by clicking on the graph displayed.

However, my problem is that while I know how to obtain a given selection from the package explorer, I have not been able to find a way to change the selection or simply open up a project in the package explorer programmatically.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: If the goal is to open one of your editors focused on a project, why does the Package Explorer have to be involved?  It might not even be open itself.

Comment: I need to handle several types of data, not all of which can be opened in an editor. In those cases I want to simply highlight it in the package explorer or, if it is a project, open it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. Eclipse does offer direct access to the package explorer in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart` , but it is discouraged.

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart;

...

PackageExplorerPart part= PackageExplorerPart.getFromActivePerspective();
IResource resource =  /*any IResource to be selected in the explorer*/;

part.selectAndReveal(resource);
```

This will highlight whatever IResource `resource` is and expand the tree as necessary.

Comment: You should also implement IShowInTargetList. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/IShowInTargetList.html

Comment: @nitind I don't really see what that would be necessary/advantageous for. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It lets your part supply a list of part IDs to be shown in the Navigate->Show In menu.

Answer (score 3):

This answer extends what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11380524/499797) states but takes it further for folks who mind the *"Discouraged Access"* warning on the use of `PackageExplorerPart`.
Exact warning (more for easier searching off Google) that you see is

> Discouraged access: The type `PackageExplorerPart` is not accessible due
>   to restriction on required library
>   `/eclipse_install_path/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.9.1.v20130820-1427.jar`

**Code Sample:**

```
final IWorkbenchPart activePart = getActivePart();
if (activePart != null && activePart instanceof IPackagesViewPart) {
    ((IPackagesViewPart) activePart).selectAndReveal(newElement);
}
```

*Supporting Code:*

```
private IWorkbenchPart getActivePart() {
    final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    final IWorkbenchWindow activeWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (activeWindow != null) {
        final IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeWindow.getActivePage();
        if (activePage != null) {
            return activePage.getActivePart();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```