# How to programmatically "Show in Project Explorer"

Tags: eclipse, plugins, project, explorer

I have developed an Eclipse view in which I handle elements that are also resources in the workspace.
I want to programmatically select the resource in Project Explorer, like "Navigate > Show in Project Explorer".
I already have the IResource in my hand.

How can I do this ?

I have seen this thread: [How to programmatically change the selection within package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335491/how-to-programmatically-change-the-selection-within-package-explorer)
It is exactly the same thing I want, except for Project Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ProjectExplorer* extends from *CommonNavigator*, so there should be the method:

```
public void selectReveal(ISelection selection);
```

If not, look for "*setSelection(ISelection, boolean)*"
Put your IResource in a IStructuredSelection or something..