# How to programmatically define the project types that the project explorer in a WizardNewFileCreationPage will display

Tags: eclipse, wizard, project-explorer

I am working on an Eclipse plugin project that implements an Import file wizard, designed for files that pertain to a custom project type. One of the wizard's pages is a `WizardNewFileCreationPage` page, where a project explorer is automatically (as far as I can see) displayed. This project explorer displays all projects available in the workspace. However, since, as I said, the files the wizard deals with are useful to one particular project type, I want to restrict the explorer and only display projects of that custom type.

I know how to select projects of a custom type:

```
  List<IProject> projectList = new LinkedList<IProject>();
  try {
     IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
     IProject[] projects = workspaceRoot.getProjects();
     for(int i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        IProject project = projects[i];
        if(project.hasNature("com.example.www.myNature")) {
           projectList.add(project);
        }
     }
  }
  catch(CoreException ce) {
     ce.printStackTrace();
  }
```

found at this link: [Get a list of all java projects open in an Eclipse workspace](https://gist.github.com/rylan/1830430)

I am assuming that the `WizardNewFileCreationPage` class includes, behind the scenes, a `TreeViewer` or something similar. In any case, how can I filter the contents of the project explorer in this wizard page?
I took a look at the following question: [How to programmatically change the selection within package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335491/how-to-programmatically-change-the-selection-within-package-explorer), but in my case the `activePart` variable is of type

```
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer
```

which does not have a `getTreeViewer()` method. It has a `createPartControl()` method:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite aParent);
```

Could this be useful for what I want? Or is it a case of using extension points?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

Although the tree shown in `WizardNewFileCreationPage` looks similar to project explorer it is not based on that code.

The code used to show the tree is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.misc.ContainerSelectionGroup` which is itself contained in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.misc.ResourceAndContainerGroup`. These classes don't support much customization and in any case aren't accessible outside of `WizardNewFileCreationPage`.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I was afraid of this. I will wait a little longer, but I suspect it's your answer that I will accept.